# When a variable in a .txt file is within multiple specific ranges, I want to change the font color of a div in a separate html file

Tags: alert, counter, twitch

Here is my situation. Keep in mind everything is local. I have an autohotkeyscript on my computer, and when I hit a specific key, the script reads a line in a txt file which is a simple number, adds 1 to that line, deletes the old file and saves the new one, thus incrimenting the variable. It would look something like this to begin with:

```
Follows: 0/5
0
5
```

and when I hit the key, it would change to this:

```
Follows: 1/5
1
5
```

What I would like to do is have a completely separate html file reference this text document, only displaying line 1 (Follows: 1/5). The script automatically increases the "goal" to 10 when it is reached (ex: Follows: 5/10), and every time the goal is reached, I want the html file displaying ONLY line 1 to change font colors to a specific color depending on which goal has been met. For example, in english:

If line 2 is greater than or equal to 0 and less than 5, font color = white.

If line 2 is greater than or equal to 5 and less than 10, font color = green.

If line 2 is greater than or equal to 10 and less than 15, font color = orange.

I would like to be able to do as many of these as I want, and when I run out of colors the final line would read:

If line 2 is greater than or equal to X. font color = black.

I'm sorry I didn't include any code to show that I've been attempting to make this work, I just really have no clue where to start. Having the page automatically update after "saving" is something I am currently working on as well. Thanks in advance for any help!